# How to install gi for anaconda python3.6

Tags: python, glade

in Ubuntu 16.04 I have python2.7, python3.5 and python3.6.
Anaconda is using python3.6. I can import gi on 2.7 and 3.5, but I can't in 3.6.
I created the link as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526026/how-to-install-gi-module-for-anaconda-python3 but I still get an error.

```
gio@gio-XPS-13-9343:~$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/gio/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
>>>
```

Comment: I switched to use PyQt instead of gi for my GUI

Answer (score 1):

I have had the very same problem today and what worked for me is the following:

**First**, create the link, as suggested in the stackoverflow post you cited (assuming that anaconda is installed under /home/your_user/anaconda3)

`ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi /home/your_user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

**Secondly**, navigate into the `gi` folder that you just linked, within your anaconda directory and rename a copy of the two .so files to fit the python-version of anaconda (in my case from **3.4** to **3.6**)

```
cd /home/your_user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/

sudo cp _gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

and

```
sudo cp _gi_cairo.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

**Finally**, the `import gi` worked accordingly within my anaconda environment.

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import gi
>>>
```

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: Python is such dogshit what a joke