# ImportError:cannot import name '_gi' while trying to add any PPA repository

Tags: 18.04, python, ppa

I have been trying to install MPV on my Ubuntu (18.04 LTS). Whenever I am trying to add a PPA repository to my system I get this error.

For example, I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
```

And got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

It happens every time I am trying to add any PPA to my system. I had Python 3.6 installed by default but later updated to Python 3.8.0. I am new to Linux. What might be causing this problem? And How to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: See my answer on similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68039322/814297

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your system might have issues choosing the correct Python version.

Try editing the file `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` and changing out the line `#!/usr/bin/python3` with the specific version of python, in your case:

`#!/usr/bin/python3.8`

Alternatively see if you have an older working version of python installed that you could use instead:

`ls -al /usr/bin | grep python`

look for other versions, like `python3.5` or `python3.6` and try replacing the `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` with the apropriate version number.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with python upgraded to 3.7. I found the method  from this link: [How to install gi for anaconda python3.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057832/how-to-install-gi-for-anaconda-python3-6) and it works for me. In your situation try to change 3.7 to 3.8 and 37 to 38:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/ /home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
cd /home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/
sudo cp _gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
sudo cp _gi_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```